# build.gradle file throws a obviously wrong exception

Tags: flutter, sdk, build.gradle

screenshot of issue

[image]

the debugger is throwing an exception about Flutter Sdk not found line in build.gradle file.

```
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}
```

but local properties is fine as far as I can see

```
sdk.dir=C:\\Users\\GNG\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk
flutter.sdk=C:\\Users\\GNG\\code\\flutter
flutter.buildMode=debug
flutter.versionName=1.0.0
flutter.versionCode=1
```

I have added `C\:\\` as seen in other threads but flutter overrides it as soon `flutter pub get` is called.

I had some errors so ran `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` this exception is not going away since.  I read that it is the path problem but the application is running hence of course its using flutter sdk. Why would this exception occur in debugger when the app is running using the sdk. I can run app in emulator and in chrome just fine.